# How to add condition (measure is greater than 0) in an MDX query

Tags: mdx

I have the following query in `MDX`

```
With

  member [Week Count] as 
     ( 
       ([WORK ].[Complying Flag].&[COMPLYING], [Measures].[No of Work ])
/([WORK ].[Complying Flag].[(All)].[All], [Measures].[No of Work ])) *100
select  
  {[Week Count]} on columns,
  {[CLOSED DATE].[Week End Date].members} on rows
FROM [test ]
```

I need to add a condition where clause `where  [Measures].[ACT LAB HRS]>0`
but it returns always error , how to correct it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Filter` but we would need a set to filter so something like this:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Week Count] as 
     ( 
       ([WORK ].[Complying Flag].&[COMPLYING], [Measures].[No of Work ])
/([WORK ].[Complying Flag].[(All)].[All], [Measures].[No of Work ])
     ) *100
SELECT  
  {[Week Count]} on columns,
  {[CLOSED DATE].[Week End Date].members} on rows
FROM [test]
WHERE
   (
    FILTER 
      (
        [SomeDimension].[SomeHierarchy].members,
        [Measures].[ACT LAB HRS]>0
      )
   );
```

Another approach would be to include a `HAVING` clause:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Week Count] as 
     ( 
       ([WORK ].[Complying Flag].&[COMPLYING], [Measures].[No of Work ])
/([WORK ].[Complying Flag].[(All)].[All], [Measures].[No of Work ])
     ) *100
SELECT  
  {
   [Measures].[Week Count],
   [Measures].[ACT LAB HRS]
  } ON 0,
  {[CLOSED DATE].[Week End Date].members} 
  HAVING [Measures].[ACT LAB HRS]>0
  ON 1
FROM [test];
```

Comment: Both the axis are "0".